# integration by parts exponential

Tags: integration, exponential-function

How do you integrate

$$\frac{x}{\sigma^2} \exp \left( \frac{-x^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)$$

I have so far tried integration by parts and have gotten stuck.

$$u= \frac{x}{\sigma^2}$$

$$du= \frac{1}{\sigma^2}$$

$$v= \frac{ -\sigma^2 \exp \left ( \frac{-x^2}{2\sigma^2} \right )  }{x} $$

$$dv= \exp \left( \frac{-x^2}{2\sigma^2} \right)$$

Then I am completely stuck

Comment: Not by parts, but by substitution, let $u=-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}$.  Note that $\sigma^2$ here is a constant.

Answer (score 1):

As told André Nicolas sigma is just a constant, and if you let $ω=\frac{-x^2}{2σ^2}$ we'll have:

$$\int \:\frac{\:x\cdot \:e^{^{\frac{-x^2}{2σ^2}}}}{σ^2}dx=-\int \:\:e^ωdω=-e^{^{\frac{-x^2}{2σ^2}}}+C$$

Where you don't understand ask me.